# Cannot get JSON object from PHP to Android

Tags: php, android, json

This is a problem with the PHP i guess!

I used Async Task in my Android App and retreived JSON Objects from the php. It works fine when i encode the JSON object in php and i'm able to get that data to Android. No Worries!
NO ERRORS!

But the problem i have is if i encode JSON array or object within **If condition** or **Loops**, i'm having a problem.

Example i'm able to retreive json data to android when my php is like this :

```
<?php
//Connecting to server, database and etc....
$a = array();
$a = array('mydata' => "halo");
print $json = json_encode($a);
?>
```

The above codes work fine and i can get the json data to my android app. But when i encode json within an if condition or a loop, my android app doesn't identify that encoded json data! Like this :

```
<?php

//Connecting to server, database and etc....
$a = array();
if (mycondition) {
    $a = array('mydata' => "Condition True");
    print $json = json_encode($a);
} else {
    $a = array('mydata' => "Condition False");
    print $json = json_encode($a);
}
?>
```

Please note that the above code works Fine when i open it with web browser. But my android app doesn't identify the json data given in the second php code! Whats the problem? i hope you can understand what i'm trying to ask!

Comment: then this is definitely not a "problem with PHP". This is either a problem with **what** you echo (isn't there noise like invisible-in-the-browser HTML tags) or with the parser you are using in the Android app.

Comment: problem with echo? didnt get it! It worked find when i open the php with the Browser. my if condition works and json is printed to the condition accordingly. but why cant my android app get the encoded data when it is within or after the if condition! That's my problem!

Comment: @userXXX now read and understand what I wrote.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal yet _complete_ example that you've tested and that didn't produce the result you're looking for? The code you've posted suggests that you're not exactly "fluent" in php, so the error might be somewhere you don't expect (and therefore do not show us).

Answer (score 0):

The if condition "should" not have any bearing on how android handles the result.

You might wanna try to print the exact same json data from your second example, without the if condition to see if there is a problem with that (the space should not really be the problem though).

The other thing you might wanna check is to put `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at the top of your script!

Comment: it works when i remove the if condition. But if i encode json data within or after the if condition, then my android app doesn't recognize!

Comment: Could you post the complete source code (or at least more of it)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the PHP header.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: I've set it but doesn't work! Now it stops giving the json encoded output in the web browser !

Comment: Try `echo $json = json_encode($a);` instead of `print $json = json_encode($a);
`

Comment: echo doesn't even display the output! :(

Comment: Sorry I'm almost asleep, you're echoing/printing the output of the assignment statement of `$json = json_encode($a);` not the actual result, you need to output the result of `json_encode($a);` like this. `echo json_encode($a);`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an example of what would be a self-contained example.

```
<?php
//Connecting to server, database and etc....
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
// setup sample data
setup($pdo);

$query = '
    SELECT
        id,value
    FROM
        soFoo
';
// processing
$data = array('a'=>array(), 'b'=>array());
foreach( $pdo->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r ) { // a loop
    if ( 0==$r['id']%2 ) { // a condition
        $data['a'][] = $r['value'];
    }
    else {
        $data['b'][] = $r['value'];
    }
}

// encode data and send to client
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);

/*
 * creates a temporary table
 * and fills it with test data
 */
function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment,
            value varchar(32),
            primary key (id)
        )
    ');

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (value) VALUES (?)');

    foreach(array('mary', 'the', 'had', 'quick', 'a', 'brown', 'little', 'fox', 'lamb') as $w ) {
        $stmt->execute( array($w) );
    }
}
```

prints

```
{"a":["the","quick","brown","fox"],"b":["mary","had","a","little","lamb"]}
```